# weights of coocurrence matrix in glove

Tags: word-embeddings, stanford-nlp

I was studying the theory behind glove and was checking out some implementations of it. Before passing the data to its neural networks, I noticed that the weights of the co-occurrence matrix aren't the counts between the target and contexts words instead, the matrix is weighted with some dist from the target to the context word. For example:

[Original Glove](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/blob/master/src/cooccur.c)  at line 332

[Pytorch Glove](https://github.com/noaRricky/pytorch-glove/blob/master/glove.py) at lines 61 and 63

And at the [paper](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf) the authors defined $X_{ij}$ like the count of contexts of a word $j$ in front of a word $i$

**Why is the co-occurrence matrix weights with this distance value in the implementations? Instead of the counts between them.**

Answer (score 0):

Whether to do distance weighting or not is an option in the GloVe code (but it is turned on by default in the C code and was used in our experiments). This is discussed and motivated in section 4.2 of the Pennington et al. paper, but I agree it is presented there as a detail rather than in the original exposition. The word2vec code did a similar-but-different distance weighting. IIRC, it isn't mentioned at all in their papers but is discussed in this paper (sec 3.1): https://aclanthology.org/Q15-1016.pdf

Comment: Can these weights be normalized in building weighted graphs?